# При использовании Spring Data JpaRepository настройки через JavaConfig, вылетает NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Уже неделю голову ломаю, вроде всё так и всё на месте, но что-то не вижу, подскажите, пожалуйста,  что не учёл

Само исключение:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type 'File.service.AddressService' available
```

main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("File.settings.ApplicationConfig.class");
    AddressService repositoryAddress =  applicationContext.getBean(AddressService.class);
    Address address = new Address();
    address.setId(13L);
    address.setCity("Lviv");
    address.setCountry("UKraine");
    address.setStreet("Shevchenka 42A");
    address.setPostCode("435433");
    repositoryAddress.save(address);
```

}

JavaConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("File.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("File")
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")

public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Resource
    private Environment env;

@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("db.user_name"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
   entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
   entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan 
   (env.getRequiredProperty("db.entity.pages"));
   entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
   entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(getProperties());
   return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager getJpaTransactionManager() {
 JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
 transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(getEntityManager().getObject());
 return transactionManager;
 }

 public Properties getProperties() {
     Properties properties = new Properties();
     InputStream inp = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hibernate.properties");
     try {
         properties.load(inp);
     } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("Can't find hibernate.propertis in classpath!" + e);
     }
     return properties;
 }
```

}

Настройки dataSource:

```
db.driver = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
db.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/public?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC
db.user_name = root
db.password = 1111
db.entity.pages = File.Entity
```

Настройки Hibernate:

```
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update
```

JpaRepository:

```
public interface RepositoryAddress extends JpaRepository<Address,Long> {
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class AddressService implements AddressDAO {
    @Autowired
    private RepositoryAddress repositoryAddress;

    @Override
    public void save(Address address) {
       repositoryAddress.saveAndFlush(address);
    }

   @Override
   public Address getById(Long id) {
       return repositoryAddress.findById(id).orElse(null);
   }

   @Override
   public List<Address> getAll() {
       return repositoryAddress.findAll();
   }

   @Override
   public void update(Address address) {
       repositoryAddress.saveAndFlush(address);
   }

   @Override
   public void deleteById(Long id) {
       repositoryAddress.deleteById(id);
   }
}
```

AddressDAO:

```
public interface AddressDAO {

    void save(Address address);

    Address getById(Long id);

    List<Address> getAll();

    void update(Address address);

    void deleteById(Long id);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: AddressService repositoryAddress =  applicationContext.getBean(AddressService.class);
    Address address = applicationContext.getBean(Address.class); это странно, потому как класс Address вообще не должен быть бином, а клаасс AddressService имплементит AddressDAO , а его вообще нет в Вашем примере. Кроме того, хотелось бы видеть именование пакетов в классах.

Comment: @Дмитрий Александрович, добавил в конце AddressDAO, и скрин наименований пакетов в классах, а с applicationContext.getBean(Address.class) и вправду что-то начудил ,исправил на обычное new Address(), но исключение вылетает выше и по итогу нету разницы как я создал экземпляр Address((

Comment: hibernate.show_dialect = true - а это вас не смущает? мало того, у вас контекст грузится непонятно откуда: ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("File.settings.ApplicationConfig"). это, видимо , должен быть файл конфигурации, но у вас явно конфигурация с помощью аннотаций. исправьте это, если не поможет, напишите - я сам подниму проект, на глаз такие вещи сложно оценить.

Comment: @Дмитрий Александрович, исправил но результат всё тот же, более того пытался сделать тоже самое но с настройками в Spring xml контейнере; ещё пробовал с xml  настройками но без использования наследника или самого CrudRepository,  ну реализовывал методы dao используя методы EntityManager. В общем пробовал и так и этак но результат, а именно исключение одно и тоже. Ощущение что ошибка очень простая и общая среди этих попыток , но я не вижу(

Comment: https://fex.net/598160563374?fileId=1295643823 - ссылка на файлообменник. распаковывайте архив и запускайте

Comment: @Дмитрий Александрович, спасибо большое, но хотелось бы узнать конкретно какую ошибку допустил в данном примере(это пример чисто для себя, для понимания)

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы я еще рабочий код сравнил с Вашим?

Comment: @Дмитрий Александрович, нет , вопрос не в получении рабочего кода, а почему этот код не рабочий в чём его загвоздка

Comment: Ну так сравните с рабочим. Там ошибок может быть больше, чем нормального кода. К тому же, имея в руках огрызки проекта, мягко говоря, сложно понять, что происходит. здесь мне не нравится ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("File.settings.ApplicationConfig.class"); - это бред в принципе. на репозитории нет аннотации. что у вас с зависимостями, только Богу известно. заодно прочитайте про правила  именования пакетов. с ума можно сойти, когда часть с большой буквы, а часть с маленькой